# Mongoose find the difference between 2 dates

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

im trying to calculate the difference between `endDate` and `startDate` for every document  in `vacations` collection to find How many vacation days does the `employee` have?  :

```
  const employee = await Employee.findOne({ nameAR: req.body.name });

  const vacations = await Vacation.find({ employeeId: employee._id });
  let numberOfDays = 0;

  vacations.map((vacation) => {

    Vacation.aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          _id: vacation._id,
          start: vacation.startDate,
          end: vacation.endDate,
          result: {
            $subtract: ["$end", "$start"],
          },
        },
      },
    ]).exec(function (err, diff) {
      vacationCount.numberOfDays = vacationCount.numberOfDays + diff;
    });
  });
```

`map` loops `vacations` array for an `employee` and `aggregate` to find the difference between dates for every `vacation` document, store it in variable `numberOfDay` and add the next one.

i have 2 problem here :
**first** : `exec` method returns an array of objects, which i dont want, i want it only to return the `result` because i dont want to map again

**second and big one** : `result` returns `null` which means `aggregate` doesn't even work properly

i've made sure `employee` and `vacations` data fetches succesfully

note: `startDate` and `endDate` could be `null` in some docs.

**vacations returned docs will be something like this** :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "631b59a8f25e201029953b31",
        "employeeId": "631b595578dae2d46f112389",
        "type": "Annual",
        "startDate": "2022-09-09T00:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2022-09-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "numberOfHours": null,
        "status": "approved",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "631b59d9f25e201029953b3d",
        "employeeId": "631b595578dae2d46f112389",
        "type": "Day time leave",
        "startDate": null,
        "endDate": null,
        "numberOfHours": "4",
        "status": "approved",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "631b59dbf25e201029953b40",
        "employeeId": "631b595578dae2d46f112389",
        "type": "Day time leave",
        "startDate": null,
        "endDate": null,
        "numberOfHours": "5",
        "status": "approved",
        "__v": 0
    },
]
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this Out and do let me know if it works for you:

```
// Finding particular Employee details from employee collection
const employee = await Employee.findOne({ nameAR: req.body.name });

// Stores Total Number of Vacation Days 
let numberOfDay  = 0;

/* Finding all matching vacation records from vaction collection,aggregate them 
and calculate no. of days between end and start date, stores it to numberOfVacationDays.*/
const vacations = await Vacation.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id",
      start: "$startDate",
      end: "$endDate",
      numberOfVacationDays: {
        $divide: [
          {
            $subtract: [
              {
                "$toDate": "$endDate"
              },
              {
                "$toDate": "$startDate"
              }
            ]
          },
          //returned mills can be converted to day by dividing by 86400000 (number of milliseconds in 24 hours)
          86400000 
        ]
      },
    },
  },

  {
    "$match": {
      employeeId: employee._id 
    }
  }

]).exec();

// Once we have all vacation days of employee ,
//we can calculate total Number Of Vacation Days and store it in numberOfDay
vacations.forEach((vacation) =>{
    if(vacation.numberOfVacationDays){
        numberOfDay  += vacation.numberOfVacationDays;
    }
});
```